# Find line items are supplied by suppliers in AFRICA for orders made by customers in UNITED STATES

Tags: mysql, sql

How to fix this code to show line items are supplied by suppliers in AFRICA for orders made by customers in UNITED STATES?

It only show like the lineitem are supplied by suppliers in AFRICA or orders of lineitem made by customers in UNITED STATES but i want the lineitem are supplied by suppliers in AFRICA and orders of lineitem made by customers in UNITED STATES.

```
select Sum(Result.counts) from (
    SELECT count(l_orderkey)  AS counts 
    FROM lineitem
    INNER JOIN orders ON lineitem.l_orderkey = orders.o_orderkey
    INNER JOIN customer ON orders.o_custkey = customer.c_custkey
    INNER JOIN nation ON customer.c_nationkey = nation.n_nationkey
    WHERE n_name = "UNITED STATES" 
    union 
    SELECT count(l_orderkey) AS counts 
    FROM lineitem
    INNER JOIN orders ON lineitem.l_orderkey = orders.o_orderkey
    INNER JOIN supplier ON lineitem.l_suppkey = supplier.s_suppkey
    INNER JOIN nation ON supplier.s_nationkey = nation.n_nationkey
    INNER JOIN region ON nation.n_regionkey = region.r_regionkey
    WHERE r_name = "AFRICA"
    )Result;
```

Those are table and keys:

```
CREATE TABLE region (
    r_regionkey  decimal(2,0) not null,
    r_name       char(25) not null,
    r_comment    varchar(152)
);
CREATE TABLE nation (
    n_nationkey  decimal(3,0) not null,
    n_name       char(25) not null,
    n_regionkey  decimal(2,0) not null,
    n_comment    varchar(152)
);
CREATE TABLE part (
    p_partkey     decimal(10,0) not null,
    p_name        varchar(55) not null,
    p_mfgr        char(25) not null,
    p_brand       char(10) not null,
    p_type        varchar(25) not null,
    p_size        decimal(2,0) not null,
    p_container   char(10) not null,
    p_retailprice decimal(6,2) not null,
    p_comment     varchar(23) not null
);
CREATE TABLE supplier (
    s_suppkey     decimal(8,0) not null,
    s_name        char(25) not null,
    s_address     varchar(40) not null,
    s_nationkey   decimal(3,0) not null,
    s_phone       char(15) not null,
    s_acctbal     decimal(7,2) not null,
    s_comment     varchar(101) not null
);
CREATE TABLE partsupp (
    ps_partkey     decimal(10,0) not null,
    ps_suppkey     decimal(8,0) not null,
    ps_availqty    decimal(5,0) not null,
    ps_supplycost  decimal(6,2) not null,
    ps_comment     varchar(199) not null
);
CREATE TABLE customer (
    c_custkey     decimal(9,0) not null,
    c_name        varchar(25) not null,
    c_address     varchar(40) not null,
    c_nationkey   decimal(3,0) not null,
    c_phone       char(15) not null,
    c_acctbal     decimal(7,2) not null,
    c_mktsegment  char(10) not null,
    c_comment     varchar(117) not null
);
CREATE TABLE orders (
    o_orderkey       decimal(12,0) not null,
    o_custkey        decimal(9,0) not null,
    o_orderstatus    char(1) not null,
    o_totalprice     decimal(8,2) not null,
    o_orderdate      date not null,
    o_orderpriority  char(15) not null,
    o_clerk          char(15) not null,
    o_shippriority   decimal(1,0) not null,
    o_comment        varchar(79) not null
);
CREATE TABLE lineitem (
    l_orderkey    decimal(12,0) not null,
    l_partkey     decimal(10,0) not null,
    l_suppkey     decimal(8,0) not null,
    l_linenumber  decimal(1,0) not null,
    l_quantity    decimal(2,0) not null,
    l_extendedprice  decimal(8,2) not null,
    l_discount    decimal(3,2) not null,
    l_tax         decimal(3,2) not null,
    l_returnflag  char(1) not null,
    l_linestatus  char(1) not null,
    l_shipdate    date not null,
    l_commitdate  date not null,
    l_receiptdate date not null,
    l_shipinstruct char(25) not null,
    l_shipmode     char(10) not null,
    l_comment      varchar(44) not null
);
```

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: The above query looks very strange...

Comment: i believe the last fifth line need to get rid off because it is useless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run an UNION ALL

```
select Sum(Result.counts) from (
    SELECT count(l_orderkey)  AS counts 
    FROM lineitem
    INNER JOIN orders ON lineitem.l_orderkey = orders.o_orderkey
    INNER JOIN customer ON orders.o_custkey = customer.c_custkey
    INNER JOIN nation ON customer.c_nationkey = nation.n_nationkey
    WHERE n_name = 'UNITED STATES'
    union ALL
    SELECT count(l_orderkey) AS counts 
    FROM lineitem
    INNER JOIN orders ON lineitem.l_orderkey = orders.o_orderkey
    INNER JOIN supplier ON lineitem.l_suppkey = supplier.s_suppkey
    INNER JOIN nation ON supplier.s_nationkey = nation.n_nationkey
    INNER JOIN region ON nation.n_regionkey = region.r_regionkey
    WHERE r_name = 'AFRICA'
    )Result;
```

or make something to differentiate both lines

```
select Sum(Result.counts) from (
    SELECT count(l_orderkey)  AS counts , 'UNITED STATES' 
    FROM lineitem
    INNER JOIN orders ON lineitem.l_orderkey = orders.o_orderkey
    INNER JOIN customer ON orders.o_custkey = customer.c_custkey
    INNER JOIN nation ON customer.c_nationkey = nation.n_nationkey
    WHERE n_name = 'UNITED STATES' 
    union
    SELECT count(l_orderkey) AS counts , 'AFRICA'
    FROM lineitem
    INNER JOIN orders ON lineitem.l_orderkey = orders.o_orderkey
    INNER JOIN supplier ON lineitem.l_suppkey = supplier.s_suppkey
    INNER JOIN nation ON supplier.s_nationkey = nation.n_nationkey
    INNER JOIN region ON nation.n_regionkey = region.r_regionkey
    WHERE r_name = 'AFRICA'
    )Result;
```

Here is a simplified version to show that both work https://dbfiddle.uk/LE5oHz95

Comment: still the same, it still count lineitem's supplier is from Africa or lineitem's customer is from united states. However I want to count lineitem supplier is from Africa and lineitem's customer is from united states.

Comment: please provide a fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/ with data for it, i doubt that my query will not gove the right answer, when the single queries work of course

Comment: how do i send the tbl file?

Comment: see my changed anwer at the end i posted a fiddle, which you can aument